# Set Specific Color to the Region Occupied by LineChart

Tags: android, colors, linechart, mpandroidchart, region

I am able to plot Marks Dynamically and set Different Color to the LineChart.Now i am having issue of, not able to fill the Color in the Region where the LineChart occupies.I have used  **setS.setDrawFilled(true);** but it Fill with only one Color.How can this issue be Solved?

```
  int getColorRandom() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int r = rand.nextInt(255);
        int g = rand.nextInt(255);
        int b = rand.nextInt(255);
        int randomColor = Color.rgb(r, g, b);
        return randomColor;

    }

  ArrayList<ILineDataSet> testDataSet1 = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < dataFilteredByTerm.size(); i++) {
                                ArrayList<JSONObject> values = dataFilteredByTerm.get(termIDs.get(i));
                                ArrayList<Entry> allMarks1 = new ArrayList<>();


                                for (int k = 0; k < values.size(); k++) {
                                    allMarks1.add(new Entry(k, values.get(k).optInt("Marks")));

                                }

                                Labels.add(jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("CourseName"));
                                System.out.println("Labels" + Labels);
                                // System.out.println("allMarks" + allMarks1);
                                setS = new LineDataSet(allMarks1, values.get(i).optString("examDescription")); // set different color for each set as your requirement testDataSet.add(set); } chart.setData(new LineData(testDataSet));
                                //testDataSet1.add(labels);


                                testDataSet1.add(setS);
                                setS.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
                                setS.setDrawValues(false);
                                // setS.setColor(Integer.parseInt((getColor.get(i))));
                                // int y= setS.setColors(getColor());
                                setS.setDrawFilled(true);
                                setS.setColors(getColorRandom());


                            }


                            //  System.out.println("Date Filtered by Date" + dataFilteredByTerm);
                            YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisRight();
                            leftAxis.setEnabled(false);
                            //chart.setBorderColor(Color.RED);


                            chart.setData(new LineData(testDataSet1));
                            chart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(Labels));
                            chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            chart.invalidate();
```

**require image**
[image]

**getting image**

[image]

> I don't know where i am doing wrong.Every time the only one Color Fill
>   all the region.How can the Region be Filled with specific line Color
>   using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

Comment: Your image link's not working .

Comment: which one ,i will update

Comment: require image and getting image link

Comment: @AdnanMaqbool updated please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Solved it myself just a simple twik and its done.

Just added this inbuilt method and output seems amazing

```
   setS.setColors(getColorRandom());
                                setS.setDrawFilled(true);
                                setS.setFillColor(getColorRandom());
```

**Image**
[image]