# MPAndroidChart, set different color to each bar of single BarDataSet

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have implemented group bar chart using MPAndroid library with three BarDataSet, Now I want to set the different colors to each bar of single BarDataSet that means each bars of each BarDataSet should be in different colors.
Is it possible?Can you please help me.

Comment: this might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055465/set-specific-color-to-the-region-occupied-by-linechart

Comment: Ok, thank you... I'll try and back to you soon.